# Is "Warning: Encountered two children with the same key" of much importance?

Tags: reactjs

> Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity
>   across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated
>   and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a
>   future version.

So that's the full warning. I know how to fix it but despite this warning my component runs just fine. My question is, is this warning something that I can ignore? If not, what's an example of a scenario where it could cause issues with my component?

Comment: I think in current version (and in development) its just a warning. Everything still works although it might be terrible for performance. just make sure you don't have duplicates keys. (you can always use the array index as the key).

Comment: Using array index as key is actually an anti-pattern: https://menubar.io/react-keys-index

Comment: if you are not going to sort the array its fine.